# how to use a new package in overleaf?

Tags: overleaf, apa7

In Overleaf (I don't have any latex experience), I'm trying to use `APA7`, which formats documents in `APA` style (7th edition). Using `APA6` is no problem, but when I replace `apa6` with `apa7` as shown below:

```
\documentclass[man, a4paper, noextraspace, apacite, floatsintext]{apa7}
```

I get this error message:

> LaTeX Error: File 'apa7.cls' not found.

- Where can I find the `apa7.cls` file?
- Do I have to install a package and/or a file and in which folder(s) *(that is, only in my project folder on overleaf and/or also on a folder on my computer)*?

Comment: You should ask overleaf support. But apparently they don't have `apa7` on their server (they are using TeXLive 2018 and `apa7` is from 2019). In the meantime, try adding all the `apa7` files to your working directory

Comment: In January 2020 Overleaf updated to TeX live 2019 (https://www.overleaf.com/blog/tex-live-2019-upgrade-january-2020). But it is not clear to me at what point that TeX live 2019 system was last updated. Since `apa7` was only added to TeX live 2019 in December 2019, it may not be available on Overleaf's system.

Comment: If Overleaf does not have `apa7` on their system things are going to be tricky. (You don't need any files on your computer, but the files need to be on the Overleaf system or your project). Since https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/apa7 distributes only the packaged `.dtx` and not the unpacked `.cls` file, it is not easy to obtain `apa7.cls` without a local install. Essentially `apa7.dtx` must be compiled with `pdftex apa7.dtx` and will then create `apa7.cls` that you could upload into your Overleaf project. But without a local install it is hard to run `pdftex apa7.dtx`.

Comment: thank you both, DG' and especially moewe for your help and the detailed explanations how to solve this problem!

Comment: _[Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.]_ `apa7` indeed isn't available on Overleaf's TL2019 at present. To make things easier, I've set up a new template in the Overleaf Gallery here: However you can still use apa7 if your project contains the necessary package files. To make things easier, we've set things up in this template:

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-and-sample-for-authoring-apa7-manuscripts/pvhtwcrvcmsp 

Projects created from this template will contain the `apa7` files, so you can use `\documentclass{apa7}`.

Comment: Dear LianTze Lim, Thank you so much for your fast and amazing support, that is really helpful!